# Conditional Formatting (If/when)

Tags: conditional-formatting

Ok so I want a row to highlight red when the date in cell C1 is more than the cell in B1, but only if this is a difference of two months or less. I am sorry, I don't know how to embed a dummy spreadsheet. So for example, if B1 (clinic appointment due date) is Sep-17 and C1 (physical checks due date) is Oct-17, I want this row to highlight. If C1 is Dec-17, I don't want the row to highlight because this is more than two months from Sep-17.

Comment: Post what you have tried. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with basic rules of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Is this on excel?

Comment: Yes excel. Conditional formatting rather than VBA if possible please

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on your new description, using Column A to represent *Clinic Appointment Date* and Column B to represent *Physical Checks Due Date*.

Use a rule based on `DAYS()`.

- Click on cell `A1`
- Choose *New rule* from the Conditional Formatting menu.
- Choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*
- In *Format values where this formula is true:*, use the below formula:

  ```
  =DAYS(B1, A1) < 60
  ```
- Set up the formatting you want to use to highlight the cells. In the image below, I've set the ones that meet your requirements for highlighting to appear in red, and applied it to the first two rows in Column A (A1 and A2):

[image]

Here's the sheet with sample data in two rows, showing the conditional formatting working as requested:

[image]

Comment: Thank but that hasn't done the trick. I tried something similar using =DATEDIFF(,d)<60 but I want it to highlight when the difference is less than 60 days between w1 and o1 AND w1 is greater than o1.

Comment: I am looking at nested if statements but just can't seem to put something together.

Comment: Sorry. Please edit your question to be more specific about what you want; that second requirement is not in your question. Drop all the noise about W1 and O1, set up sample data in a few rows in A and B (three or four sets of dates) so we have something to work with, and explain the problem, including which of the rows of your sample data **should** be highlighted and which **should not**, and I'll try to help. I'm not going to continue working trying to guess what you're asking. Leave me a comment here (either to this answer or by using the @ syntax) when you've done so.

Comment: Hi Ken, I see your point. I have tried to explain it better. See what you think.

Comment: The formula I gave you above works perfectly for what you've described in your edit. See my edit, with step by step instructions and sample data and the resulting conditional formatting

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your time on this. For some reason I am unable to reproduce what you've clearly demonstrated. I will look into this. I've played with format of the data from 'custom' to 'date' and tried it with different data, but I cannot get the results you have. I am using 2010 version so am not sure that you are using a different version? I will continue to play with what you've suggested and see what happens, but it is confusing that I cannot seem to replicate the results you've demonstrated. Any suggestions are welcome!